# Popups not showing on layer/feature/marker groups

Tags: leaflet

I had two problems.  One was that, once I got lots of markers in one layer, and lots of polylines in another, someof my markers, starting from the north, started to vanish.
I noted in the doco that the zindex is derived initially from the latitude,so I bumped the offset up to +1000 for my markers, and -1000 for my polylines, and things look ok.
But I need the popups.
This suggests they actually dont work
https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster/issues/180
So I've had to dump leaflets groups, and do my own layer management.
Further more, the popups seem to vanish when I use optional baselayers.
is this right ?